# Word for "Workingness"

Tags: word-choice

I know "workingness" is not a word, but I am looking for a word that means it. For example: Evaluate the workingness of capitalism?

Comment: Well, what does it mean?

Comment: it means how good something works

Comment: Have you considered "effectiveness" or "efficacy"?

Comment: Well here is how it would be in the sentence - The point of Serving

Comment: Never mind that one here: The point of Serving in Florida by Barbara Ehrenreich is to disillusion the middle class about the blank of the American Dream.

Comment: How about "viability"?

Comment: Yes viability, I think that is best.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what exactly you are trying to express. "effectiveness", as already suggested in the comments, should work in many contexts. Definition from [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/effectiveness):

> The degree to which something is successful in producing a desired result; success.

The other word that came to mind is "viability". Definition of "viable" from the same source ([Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/viable)):

> Capable of working successfully; feasible.

To me, "effectiveness" fits better if it's established that something works to some degree, and the question is how well it works. "viability" fits better if you question that it works at all.

For example, if somebody suggests a solution for a problem, and I don't think it will work, I would call it "not viable". If I think that it could probably work, but not very well, I would call it "not effective".